# How to configre network card on centos?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ethernet, network-adapter

I have a fresh install of Centos on a machine with two NICs, one built-in and  another one installed in PCI slot. However in the network settings I get one shown as wired connection picking up IP from DHCP and working but other as unknown with not much functionality. When I use

`lspci | grep -i 'ethernet'`

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
07:09.0 Ethernet controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6102 [Rhine-II] (rev 43)
```

How do I get the other one to work?

When I run **ifconfig -a** I get:

`~]$ ifconfig -a
        enp0s25: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fd6e:957e:20a2:0:218:71ff:fe7f:d316  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
        inet6 fe80::218:71ff:fe7f:d316  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 00:18:71:7f:d3:16  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8459  bytes 7719475 (7.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6638  bytes 1066031 (1.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  memory 0xf0500000-f0520000`

`lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 666 (666.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 666 (666.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

When I use **lsmod | grep -i rhine**
I get nothing just the prompt

`[kunwar@System5 ~]$`

When I try **modprobe via-rhine**: 

`[kkhalid@System5 ~]$ modprobe via-rhine
modprobe: FATAL: Module via-rhine not found.
[kkhalid@System5 ~]$ modprobe rhine
modprobe: FATAL: Module rhine not found.
[kkhalid@System5 ~]$`

Comment: Does it show up in `ifconfig -a` ?

Comment: This is what I get I get when I use this command: enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

Comment: I guess the other oner is just a loop-back interface

Comment: Always [edit] your question if you provide new info.  Please can you try `lsmod | grep -i rhine` ?  I think the module needed isn't installed.

Comment: @Paul Is this something related driver? I new to Linux. Can this link be of any use: http://download.viatech.com/en/support/driversSelect.jsp

Comment: Linux drivers come with the distribution, there is usually no reason to download anything.  Try `modprobe via-rhine`, and if this doesn't error, try `ifconfig -a` again

Comment: @Paul It gives me an error

Comment: In `/lib/modules/[your kernel version]/kernel/drivers/net` there should be a file called `via-rhine.ko`.  Is it there?  `uname -a` will tell you your kernel.

Comment: I was searching on internet and this is what I found.... I guess it's not supported anymore.